# How to refresh Dynamics NAV cache from SQL?

Tags: sql-server, caching, dynamics-nav-2016

I would like to know if somebody knows how Dynamics NAV cache works.

I'm really a beginner of NAV, but I tested this:

- If I update or delete (not insert) a row in a table by SQL, NAV doesn't update its internal cache and sometimes refreshing its page I can see new data, for some table I have to restart the service.
- I can setup more the one application server, they will be connected each other only by SQL database, I gather that application server can syncronize their cache using SQL tables (timestamps or metadata...).

My question is: is it possibile to force the cache expiration of internal NAV cache only by SQL? If no, how can two application server sync their cache?

I know that data manipulation via SQL is highly discouraged, but please help me to understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Mak, yes, for application I mean NAV server. I'm quite sure there is a cache due to the first pt I wrote. If you try to change some value directly in the database you will not find istantly this edit in NAV and you have to refresh the page.

Comment: I think the server syncronization is made using $ndo$cachesync table for some tables. But not really clear how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [SELECTLATESTVERSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355033(v=nav.90).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the solution for everyone, but I solved my issue in test by just restarting the "Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server" service. Again, this solution is not without its issues (kicking users off, etc.) but it was the solution for me.

Comment: I know this force a full refresh from db... but this not really an answer :-)